# How can I increase the capacity of PostgreSQL text indexing?

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-indexing

I want to do indexing on Django text field which has more than 60000 characters in some rows. Right now I am having the following error (for a much smaller row):

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: index row requires 8368 bytes, maximum size is 8191
```

Is there a limit on the size for indexing in PostgreSQL?

Comment: That is a known limitation; but even if it would be possible I don't think it
would be a good idea. Why on Earth would I search using a big field?

What kind of content are you trying to index?

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to index large TEXT fields then you’ll have to look at full text indexing with [Tsearch2](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/tsearch/V2/). Also recommend to find another approach to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I want to implement search for news articles in my database in a django project based on their content. Is tsearch2 compatible with django?